# How can I disable Finder notifications?

Tags: macos, finder, notifications

Every time I disconnect my mac from its dock, I get a Finder notification about ejecting a drive before disconnecting. It's a drive I use for time machine backup, and I just don't think it's worth it to take the time to eject it every time I want to move my mac.

Is there a way to disable this notification? The Finder app does not appear in the Notification settings.

Comment: I would reconsider the decision to not safely eject the drive. You will get away with it 99 out of 100 times, but if you do it whilst it is writing or if it hasn't flushed the write cache you stand a good chance of damaging the drive. Is it worth it for the 5 seconds it would take to eject it safely?

Comment: if it hasn't flushed the write cache, isn't that simply lost data? i'm ok with that since it can try another backup when I reconnect it

Comment: No. You risk file system corruption, ie, you lose everything.

Comment: ugh. ok I guess I'll have to start ejecting it. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up putting the drive on the network using a raspberry pi. Here's the tutorial I followed for anyone wanting to save a few seconds each day

https://mudge.name/2019/11/12/using-a-raspberry-pi-for-time-machine/

Answer (score 1):

From what it looks like there isn't a decent way to do this without unloading the entire Notification Center and any other notifications alongside with it.

However, as @Tetsujin noted and as many other people would also concur, for the sake of your drive and how macOS uses it I'd personally recommend just ejecting it for the sake of your data and not to risk nuking that drive even if the chances are small; annoying but necessary with how the file system deals with write caching.